# ¿Porque no puedo crear la base de datos con doctrine?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, doctrine, symfony4

Buen día. Estoy intentando crear una base de datos con doctrine en Symfony 4, ya cree las entitidades, pero cuando ejecuto el comando `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el contenidodel archivo .env es el siguiente:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/sgisi
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

ya lo he comprobado varias veces pero no veo problema, 
alguien pudiese decirme como solucionarlo. Gracias.

Comment: ese error suele ser una mala configuracion de la cadena de BBDD que hay en el archivo .env de tu proyecto. PUedes publicar el contenido de ese archivo?

Comment: ya lo he publicado

Comment: ok. Parece estar bien. Has cambiado en el config/packages/doctrine.yaml el driver de bbdd a `pdo_pgsql`?

Comment: si lo he cambiado a pdo_pgsql pero no estoy seguro de haberlo hecho de forma correcta. Me ayudarias si me dieras un ejemplo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: no he usado postgresql con symfony, suelo trabajar mas con mysql. Este enlace puede ayudarte. http://chrishodgsonweb.co.uk/symfony/2018/05/17/symfony4-postgress/. Aunque es para instalacion en osx, la configuracion de symfony es la misma.